# ORA-00838: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 1600M ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

Tags: oracle-19c

I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-00838: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 1600M
> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

How  do I fix this error?

Comment: Increase the `memory_target` value perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Oracle documentation for `MEMORY_TARGET` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MEMORY_TARGET.html).

From the docs:

> MEMORY_TARGET should be set higher than or equal to the sum of the current sizes of the SGA and PGA.

> In a text-based initialization parameter file, if you omit MEMORY_MAX_TARGET and include a value for MEMORY_TARGET, then the database automatically sets MEMORY_MAX_TARGET to the value of MEMORY_TARGET. If you omit the line for MEMORY_TARGET and include a value for MEMORY_MAX_TARGET, the MEMORY_TARGET parameter defaults to zero. After startup, you can then dynamically change MEMORY_TARGET to a nonzero value, provided that it does not exceed the value of MEMORY_MAX_TARGET.

> Total memory usage can grow beyond the value of MEMORY_TARGET. For example, memory is allocated to PL/SQL tables and varrays regardless of the value of MEMORY_TARGET as long as memory is available at the operating system level.